# Implementing SCRAM - nonce validation and server/client keys

Tags: security, authentication

Technically two questions - but they are so heavily related I didn't want to split them up; but if the community feels I should, I will.

Following a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290073/157701) I am implementing SCRAM for a website login and web service API.  Client environments will be .Net and Javascript (with Java likely in the future).

My first issue is basic: [The protocol utilises a client and server key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802#section-3) as key steps in the authentication process; and yet in order to be validated, both need to be known by both parties in advance since the protocol doesn't allow for exchange of these (to do so would result in a bit of a chicken and egg scenario).  If you consider a Javascript client, for example, this means both keys are likely to be constants defined in the source - thus making them easy to fetch.  So: why bother?  Is it just to mitigate against 'Eve' where that 'Eve', for some reason, hasn't bothered to get the JS or client source code, which will necessarily be public!?

Secondly, like practically any other authentication mechanism it requires a client + server nonce.

Given that the authentication nonce, by definition, should never be used more than once (at least by the same user), this presumably means that a server must maintain a record of all nonce values used by all users *forever*.  Unlike other data that we regularly archive off, such a table is only ever going to get bigger and queries against it likely to get slower and slower!

If that's correct, then it's technically unfeasible to implement this or almost any other authentication mechanism!  Since I know that's plainly ridiculous; it must be common to define some additional scope that factors in a reasonable timescale as well.

As always with authentication and encryption; despite being a very experienced software developer I feel like I'm going back to school!  What am I missing!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both need to be known by both parties
>   in advance since the protocol doesn't
>   allow for exchange of these (to do so
>   would result in a bit of a chicken and
>   egg scenario).

Yes that's correct. Challenge response isn't a key-exchange protocol. It only norms, once client and server share a key, how to compute the same value from that key without transmitting in clear the key via network.

> If you consider a Javascript client,
>   for example, this means both keys are
>   likely to be constants defined in the
>   source - thus making them easy to
>   fetch.

That's not a good idea. Alternatively client and server can agree on a key during a preliminary registration process.

> Given that the authentication nonce,
>   by definition, should never be used
>   more than once (at least by the same
>   user), this presumably means that a
>   server must maintain a record of all
>   nonce values used by all users
>   forever.

NO. A new nonce should be generated for each new session using pseudo-random number generation. It's very improbable that you will get the same nonce twice, anyway It doesn't matter if a nonce it has already been used if the attacker don't know that .

Comment: Hi @0verbose - I'm not entirely sure about the nonce thing - everything I read says that it must be unique; in this case never used during an auth exchange for that user. Also I've done some digging around; and found http://www.gnu.org/s/gsasl/coverage/lib/scram/client.c.gcov.frameset.html - GNU an implementation of a SCRAM client - in which both client key and server key are `#DEFINEd` as constants; reading and through the RFC again, I'm not sure that knowledge of the key actually helps an attacker either; because of the way the proofs are derived.  I could be wrong though!

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: first of all excuse me for my poor English, maybe I'm not able to explain it so well. Anyway regarding the nonce I've never heard about the need to store every exchanged nonce. I think that if they are generated with a truly pseudo-random generator they are fine ( maybe I'm wrong). For what concern constant keys I'm pretty sure they can't be a constant. Despiting the type of cryptography technique or authentication method you are using (a/symmetric encryption, challenge/response, etc..)a SECRET is needed. If I know both the key and the cypher technique than there is no secret

Comment: If the key is a constant then everyone  knows that and there is no secret. Read careful the code you posted: http://www.gnu.org/s/gsasl/coverage/lib/scram/client.c.gcov.frameset.html . The key used in gsasl_hmac_sha1 function isn't a constant (CLIENT_KEY) but salted_password.

Comment: @0verbose - Doh! The bloody key is the first parameter... oh dear I'm just going to have a lie down...

Comment: @0verbose as for the issue over the nonce - a server shouldn't trust that a client will never repeat the same nonce: that is a specific attack vector that a malicious client might attempt.  You are right that a 'properly generated' nonce will rarely ever be repeated; but AFAIK the reason nonces should be tracked is for when they are *not* properly generated.

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: usually both client and server generates nonces in challenge response schemes. The most important one is generated by the server (the client nonce in certain schemes can not even be used). So it is the server it self that must pay attention in generating it correctly.

Comment: @0verbose - that is a fair point; in this case we are building one nonce from two; and so combined they should always be unique.

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: yes. If the server nonce is correctly generated then it should be always unique even if the client generate always the same value.